# Running SQL query twice with different conditions in where clause / oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to run the same query twice with different conditions in the WHERE clause.

1.

```
insert into t1
select sum(q) from t2
where t2.n in (select * from t3);
```

2. 

```
insert into t1
select sum(q) from t2
where t2.n NOT in (select * from t3);
```

t3 is a table of 1 column here.
the result should be 2 lines in the t1.

I was thinking of using loop and parameters, but can't seem to figure out the exact way.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just make it one statement via `where t2.n in (...) or t2.n not in (...)`?

Comment: Hi @ThorstenKettner, no as the query creates an aggregated value and I need 2 lines inserted one after another in t1: an aggregate of all rows where  t2.n in (select * from t3) and an aggregate of all rows t2.n NOT in (select * from t3). You suggestion will return 1 aggregated value

Comment: Okay, then you may want `UNION ALL`: `insert into t1 query1 union all query2`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner the thing is there is a huge script between 'insert into t1' and the where clause, and repeating it twice might lead to mistakes when updating it as I would need to update two equal scripts. Thus I am looking for the way not to repeat the script

Comment: You have simplified the queries a lot in your example. How much do the real statements differ. Is it really only `IN` in one query and `NOT IN` in the other?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes, the only difference is this one line in the where clause.

Comment: How about hiding some of the complexity of the where clause in a view ? Then you don't need to update the script anymore if there are changes - just the view(s)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a case statement to conditionally group your rows.

```
insert into t1
select sum(q) from t2
group by CASE WHEN t2.n in (select * from t3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

I think it's surprising that you don't want to also insert some kind of label for the group sum. I would have done something like this:

```
select sum(q),  
    CASE WHEN t2.n in (select * from t3) THEN 'IN' ELSE 'NOT IN' END as label
from t2
group by CASE WHEN t2.n in (select * from t3) THEN 'IN' ELSE 'NOT IN' END
```